# What are the benefits of using migrations and model classes in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

> Migrate (php artisan migrate)

I am using laravel for my app. I read laravel doc in which they say "If you have ever had to tell a teammate to manually add a column to their local database schema, you've faced the problem that database migrations solve."

But i am working with my 2 team member and we use a live db server. Everything i changes goes to live db and all find that. 
If i use live db, should i use db migtration as DOC says it is useful for local db?

> Model Class

I used model class only for Auth (for the table users and roles). For all of my query result i used raw sql query like:

```
$hal = DB::select('SELECT TotalForeignTruck,
            (( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(truck_receivedate)- UNIX_TIMESTAMP(truck_entrydate))/60/60/24) AS HoltageDay
             FROM(
            SELECT 
            (SELECT truck_entry_regs.truckentry_datetime FROM  truck_entry_regs WHERE truck_entry_regs.manf_id=m.id  ORDER BY truck_entry_regs.id ASC LIMIT 1)AS truck_entrydate,
            (SELECT truck_entry_regs.receive_datetime FROM  truck_entry_regs WHERE truck_entry_regs.manf_id=m.id  ORDER BY truck_entry_regs.id DESC LIMIT 1)AS truck_receivedate,
            (SELECT COUNT(truck_entry_regs.id) FROM  truck_entry_regs WHERE truck_entry_regs.manf_id=m.id )AS TotalForeignTruck

            FROM manifests m
            WHERE m.manifest=? ) t', [$r->mani_No]);

    return json_encode($hal);
```

I am using this (sql raw) because i can check my complex query in sqlyog then paste in my controller function. I am not sure whether some complex query can be made in eloquent query that uses model class.

My question is should i use always migration whether live or local DB?
Should i always use Model class for all of my tables?
Should i use migration even if i am on production mode (i mean if need some modification from my client when app on live)?
Does migration work on live?

Am i doing something wrong? How can i proper use of laravel features?

Answer (score 4):

Short answers:

> should i use always migration whether live or local DB

Yes, migration will help to sync DB changes among multiple environments. Meaning each change will be updated to all env perfectly and correctly. And migration will help to safely rollback DB if there is any error.

> Should i always use Model class for all of my tables

It's up to you. You have to know exactly what you are doing with the migration. Model class will help you easy to implement and reduce human issues.

> Should i use migration even if i am on production mode (i mean if need some modification from my client when app on live)

IMO, absolutely yes - as the 1st answer

> Does migration work on live?

Yes, it should work for any environment

Answer (score 1):

First, doing development on a live production server is NOT recommended, by anyone, and you really ought to stop that immediately.

Secondly, migrations help with that by easily keeping all of your DB instances in sync.

Another huge advantage is that your SQL changes are documented, over time, in source code and probably backed up in revision control (git, etc.).

---

As for Eloquent, you don't have to use it. I don't, by choice. But you really should utilize what are called Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) and create your own Database Access Layer (DBAL) using the raw SQL. Just don't have it strewn about your app willy nilly.

Comment: You prohibited to use migration in live. But if i am working with team then how all member will get the db easily if i use git? usig Export and import .sql fie?

Comment: are you trying to copy your development server data to live?

Comment: for example : my db connection will be a live ip from godaddy. i will use always this db for local work. if my local work done then i will upload only files to server. can i do this? or i have to do all in local then upload db and files?

Answer (score 1):

**Its not recommended to develop on production server.**

> My question is should i use always migration whether live or local DB?

yes.Its not required but its recommended to use migration in both and should be same migration files that would make source control and management easier and could test compatibility issues. If you keep migrations that way you can just git clone and start from where it is.

> Should i always use Model class for all of my tables?

Not all tables are required to have models, but its good to have model for each object entities like tables(users,sessions,addresses,etc) other than pivots(many to many intermediate table. eg: like user_role,role_permission). Some cases it's good to create models for pivots as well, suppose if you want to use it as an entity(eg: can create a model named Subscription for customer_movie pivot).

> Should i use migration even if i am on production mode (i mean if need
>   some modification from my client when app on live)?

yes. as migrations are used for management of incremental, reversible changes to your db its always recommended to keep same migrations in both development and production environments. when you run migrate command it only runs the new migrations(up method) as incremental and when you run rollback command it reverses the migration (down method) in order last ran migration first. so you can bring incremental updates easily. if anything goes wrong could revert back to previous condition.(only if the down method is written to reverse whats done on up method). to create tables you can use Schema::create and to modify you can you Schema::table.

> Does migration work on live?

yes. It works on both development and production. When you set environment to production when you run php artisan migrate it will prompt for each to confirm for safety. If you want to just run only the migrations that are required, you can do that too.

Comment: for first paragraph answer: If i  finished half of the task and another member want to be join how can he get all data with db after git clone?  does migration  contain data? @aimme

Comment: Does migration force to forget sql knowledge as all create, alter sql query is managed by it?

Comment: what we usually do is if the migration manupulates data. suppose if migration creates a new column and copies data into that we do that process in migration files. data itself is not contained in the migrations.so if you want give data in give a dump to him or if dummy data seeders would do that.

Comment: Won't it work? IF my member clone from git and import my .sql file i will sent him exporting from my local ?

Comment: dont use git nor include it into source code to share dump.just give him a dump and say to import.

Comment: so , you are suggesting not to track .sql file in git, right?

Comment: Ya.data doesn't go to version control.just the structure goes to version control.

Comment: how do i do ? using migration or exporting only structure in .sql file and track this in git?

Comment: Write the structure on migrations(on source code). Dump data to sql and let others import alternative way for loading development data is by creating dummy data using laravel factory and seeder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154662/discussion-between-fawel-and-aimme).

Answer (score 0):

Ad Migrations - my experience.

When I started with Laravel, I didn't get the full benefit of migrations, so I managed my database manually using phpMyAdmin. It is working well on localhost. However, I developed my project on localhost, than tested it on the stage server and then moved it to the production.  Suddenly, I had 3 databases to manage and they were supposed to be the same.

What happened was, that I forgot to update the live DB and after pushing the latest version to the production, the web crashed at some point due to the DB differences, e.g. data type/ foreign keys/constraints. And it is a nightmare to localize the issue.

Migrations let you keep track of the changes which definitely will occur during development. E.g. adding new column, changing data types, changing foreign keys etc.

If you work in a team, there might be more local versions of your app. The DB management will become extremely difficult without migrations.

Comment: so you suggest to use migration , right? but for me , it seems hard! I am now using direct mysql (sqlyog) and export in .sql then send it to my member and all files are manged by git. What is your final suggestion to manage project that will have 50+ tables and have to manage/changes during production?

Comment: @Fawel Any system that is able to track changes is better than anything done manually as I did. Even though it might seem like a small project at first, the troubles are not worth it. So, the answer is not that straightforward. If the system you are using now works fine, then you might not need migrations at all. Seems like SQLyog is a great tools that covers everything migrations would.

Comment: @Fawel Consider these questions:  1) Are you able to fully track DB changes? 2) Is it easy to propagate DB updates within your team? 3) Is it possible to track who did what change in the DB structure?  4)Is it easy to apply the DB changes in other project instances (local, stage, testing, production)?  If you answer yes, then your system probably does everything needed.

Comment: I am not sure! I told that i use sqlyog only. But what i want to be sure about using migration. If i use migration, can i do anything using in model? I mean alter table, assign foreign key, all data type that mysql support? Does laravel model class support these? has it (model) any limitation ? What if i want to use sqlyog for sometimes for some tables? @Peter Matisko

Comment: @Fawel You can do everything using Migrations. You can also create your own pure sql queries. No limitations at all. Migrations just encapsulate everything. The decision you are trying to make is not that serious as you might perceive it. You can create migrations anyt time in the future. It will just bring some work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. @peter